# Best ways to detect double memset in a large C codebase?

Tags: c

What are the best ways to detect double memset in a large C codebase?

I'm looking for some static analysis-based way to detect it.

In some cases, people usually do a memset on large structure and also do memset on a part of the structure later on which is not required. Just wanted to know if we can find a way to detect that.

Comment: Probably most code flow analysis tools could do it, e.g. [CodeQL](https://codeql.github.com/).

Comment: How did you dedetect that there is a double `memset` in the first place?

Comment: How will you know that every buffer ever passed to that function, now and in the future, has been pre-cleared to a particular value? My opinion would be it's harmless unless it is a performance issue discovered by profiling.

Comment: In some cases, people usually do a memset on large structure and also do memset on a part of the structure later on which is not required. Just wanted to know if we can find a way to detect that.

Comment: Are you talking within a single function or across functions? E.g., suppose function f1 memsets a large structure, and then passes it to function f2, which memsets a part of that structure. Is that something you want to identify? (That is harder than just finding double-memsets within a single function.) You'd probably have to write a custom extension to an existing static analysis tool.

Comment: @RaymondChenIm looking for detection across functions. But as a starter, if I can do it within a function is also fine. I want to understand if it's possible to detect it if the variables are different.

Comment: Within a single function, gcc and clang detect it just fine and memset just once: https://godbolt.org/z/chPeqGEEn . Probably also within multiple ones if the function bodies are visible and static/inlinable.

Comment: Perhaps you could develop a stragegy to replace all `malloc`/`memset` pairs with `calloc`s. Any remaining `memset`s will be those done on substructures.